# re-evaluate an msbuild item group

Tags: msbuild

I have an item group that includes a location which may or may not contain files. If there are no files present at the point the item group is declared, is it possible to re-evaluate the item group at a later time to pick up files that may have been generated in the new location, or will I have to declare an identical item group at this time and use that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have to create a new itemgroup. They are evaluated once and the value is saved, not the formula used to select files. Thus you can't "re-evaluate" these items.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I wonder why there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 9):

Item groups declared statically (outside of a Target, as a child element of the ) will be evaluated when the file is loaded.  Item groups declared dynamically (within a <Target>) will be evaluated at the moment the execution passes through the target.  For cases where the files are created during the build, you really should use a dynamic Item group.

Comment: My item group is declared in a target, I want to evaluate the item group later on within the same target.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-define the ItemGroup by first `removing` the items, and the re-including the items:

```
<Target Name="Later on" >
   <ItemGroup>
      <ClCompile Remove="@(ClCompile)" />
      <ClCompile Include="something here of your choice" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Or if you don't want nor need to remove items, you can always simply append or add to the previously existing item group:

```
<Target Name="Later on" >
   <ItemGroup>
      <ClCompile Include="Add Even more stuff" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```